# How do you list the packages flagged as outdated using pacman?

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

How can I list the packages that have been flagged as outdated on the remote repository.  I can check [archlinux.org/packages](https://archlinux.org/packages/) and see the desired information here:
[image: list of packages on remote, one is flagged out of date]

When I run `yay --show --stats` I see flagged packages in the AUR like this:
[image: yay showing a remote package is flagged out of date]

But this doesn't show information about packages installed with pacman.  To be extra clear I am not talking about my system being out of date.  I am talking about packages on the remote repository that are flagged as out of date.  When a remote package is out of date it looks like this on archlinux.org:

[image: showing a package on archlinux.org thats flagged as being out of date]

1. How can I see all the pacman installed flagged as out of date packages on my system?
2. Is there a simple way to show pacman and yay packages that our flagged at the same time?
3. If it can't be done using yay or pacman, can it be done with another program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need jq installed first then run this command

```
comm -12 \
<(curl -Ss 'https://archlinux.org/packages/search/json/?arch=any&flagged=Flagged' | jq '.results[].pkgname' | tr -d '"' | sort) \
<(pacman -Qq | sort)
```

[image: the fast pacman command]
this command is faster, but doesn't show all of the ones out of date

or

```
for package in $(pacman -Qq); do
    curl -Ss "https://archlinux.org/packages/search/json/?name=${package}&flagged=Flagged" | jq -r '.results[].pkgname'
done
```

[image: the slow pacman command]

this command is slower, but shows every package out of date

[source](https://old.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/tvnorq/finding_installed_packages_that_are_flagged_out/)